# Does changing the opacity of ADBannerView affect its correct functioning?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, iad, adbannerview

In order to not totally obscure a chunk of my game's screen, I changed the opacity of the `ADBannerView` to 0.6.

The ads still seem to load perfectly and are easily readable, etc. at least in testing.

When launched, will this cause any functionality problems with the ads?

This question hints at a possible answer, but isn't necessarily backed up with anything conclusive: [iAd Banner is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267770/iad-banner-is-not-working)

I've done some research and have found no evidence in Apple's Docs about ADBannerView opacity causing problems--but can see that messing with ad transparency could make it so the ads themselves don't load because they aren't being used "correctly".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about App Store approval and not computer programming.  You may want to submit it as a sample question at the [proposed App Stores Stack Exchange site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54103/app-stores?referrer=Yv2JRQtW0MVr1FeOcN4Y-A2).

Comment: Also this question is about (1) the future and (2) Apple's behavior, both of which are totally unpredictable.

Comment: It's about ADBannerView transparency being allowed in an app, will it mess up functionality? Does it break iOS guidelines? It's a valid question that has to do with a programming element of the iOS platform.

Comment: Fixed wording, asked a more programmatic question rather than app approval question. Consider taking off hold.