# Could not instantiate class named ADBannerView

Tags: ios, adbannerview

i am trying to inset an iad banner at the bottom of my app but keep getting errors after following tutorials.
code as follows.

```
@interface DMKHomeViewController (UIViewcontroller ) <ADBannerViewDelegate>{

}
@end

@implementation DMKHomeViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

[banner setAlpha:1];

[UIView commitAnimations];

}



- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)

banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error

{

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

[banner setAlpha:0];

[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

i keep getting the following error
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named ADBannerView'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: possible duplicate of [iAd Banner is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267770/iad-banner-is-not-working)

Comment: @MikeAsp Hey bud mind marking my answer as the selected one?  Thanks in advance.  Cheers.

Answer (score 20):

Please make sure that you have added the "iAd.framework"...

To do this go to the "App. Target", "General" and scroll down until you see "Linked Frameworks and Libraries".  Hit "+" and select the iAd framework.  See screen captures below...

[image: App. Target -> General]

[image: '+' to add, search for iAd]

Comment: In my case, this is the correct answer. I decided to include an adBannerView inside a nib, but forgot to import the framework into my project and do this.

Comment: @CoachRoebuck Hey! Just saw this.  I am glad that this helped you!  It is hard to keep track of all the frameworks, especially in a big project...  So easy to forget.

Answer (score 0):

You have not created object of AdBannerview..

First, create object for banner view and set delegate for it.

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad
{
   [self createBannerView];
}
- (void)createBannerView {

  Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView");
  if (cls) {
    ADBannerView *adView = [[cls alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];


    // Set the current size based on device orientation
    adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;
    adView.delegate = self;

    adView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

    // Set initial frame to be offscreen
    CGRect bannerFrame =adView.frame;
    bannerFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height;
    adView.frame = bannerFrame;

    self.bannerView = adView;
    [self.view addSubview:adView];
    [adView release];
  }
}
```

Comment: no that didnt work either ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier is depreciated

Comment: First you create object and set delegate...without writing first ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier and check and run........and for more detail..http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/09/16/placing-iad-banners-at-the-top-of-a-table-view.html     see this tutorial in more detail...