# iOS Simulator executing app, but "crashes" when pressing on "Button"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

On Xcode 6 Beta 2, I have built an app with 2 viewcontrollers.
[image]

You can see that the action of "Button" is to open the second ViewController.

But when pressing on "Button", theres a focus on Xcode, and shows me this screen:
[image]
And highlights the green code-line.
How can I fix it?

**Notice, I havent wrote any code what so ever, just created the Storyboard.

Console:

```
2014-06-26 01:05:54.957 ColorMatcher[878:11914] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named ADBannerView'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00447646 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01d728e3 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0044756d +[NSException raise:format:] + 141
    3   UIKit                               0x010f53c0 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 317
    4   UIKit                               0x010f5768 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1253
    5   UIKit                               0x010f527b -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 371
    6   UIKit                               0x00caf579 -[UIView initWithCoder:] + 867
    7   UIKit                               0x010f5566 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 739
    8   UIKit                               0x010f527b -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 371
    9   UIKit                               0x00f64b31 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 189
    10  UIKit                               0x010f5566 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 739
    11  UIKit                               0x010f5768 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1253
    12  UIKit                               0x010f527b -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 371
    13  UIKit                               0x00f63927 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1164
    14  UIKit                               0x00d9274d -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 270
    15  UIKit                               0x00d92ff4 -[UIViewController loadView] + 295
    16  UIKit                               0x00d93222 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 72
    17  UIKit                               0x00d9377b -[UIViewController view] + 35
    18  UIKit                               0x013daed5 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 75
    19  UIKit                               0x00d6af51 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentingViewController:presentedViewController:] + 113
    20  UIKit                               0x00d6b005 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresenting:presented:] + 48
    21  UIKit                               0x00da0564 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 1952
    22  UIKit                               0x00da3061 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 333
    23  UIKit                               0x00da31e2 -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:] + 57
    24  UIKit                               0x0124df79 -[UIStoryboardModalSegue perform] + 271
    25  UIKit                               0x0123b8e6 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 217
    26  UIKit                               0x0123b962 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 116
    27  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01d8579d -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    28  UIKit                               0x00c45fe2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 99
    29  UIKit                               0x00c45f74 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64
    30  UIKit                               0x00d72876 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 69
    31  UIKit                               0x00d72c93 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 598
    32  UIKit                               0x00d71efd -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 660
    33  UIKit                               0x00c952da -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 874
    34  UIKit                               0x00c95db5 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 791
    35  UIKit                               0x00c5bc29 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    36  UIKit                               0x00c6b5e2 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 20518
    37  UIKit                               0x00c40cc5 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2154
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x0036bfaf __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x0036134d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x003608a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 952
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x0036022b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x0036005b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    43  GraphicsServices                    0x03d943ca GSEventRunModal + 192
    44  GraphicsServices                    0x03d94207 GSEventRun + 104
    45  UIKit                               0x00c446e5 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    46  ColorMatcher                        0x00002ae1 top_level_code + 97
    47  ColorMatcher                        0x00002b1b main + 43
    48  libdyld.dylib                       0x022b3ac9 start + 1
    49  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Just remove the `ADBannerView` and check

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iAd Banner is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267770/iad-banner-is-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

You need to link with the iAd library.

Click on your project in the Project Navigator on the left side. Select your application under "Targets". Then under "General" add "iAd.framework" to the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries".