# Error Could not instantiate class named ADBannerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, iad

I've correctly implemented iAd by adding it to my frameworks, importing it as `#import <iAd/iAd.h>`, and delegating itself in the didload method and here:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController  <FBSDKSharingContent,ADBannerViewDelegate, FBSDKSharing, FBSDKSharingDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, SegueingInfoProtocol, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate> {
    UIWebView *webView;
}
```

but when I execute my application I get this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate
>   class named ADBannerView'

I can't get that, I implemented iAd into other apps in the same way, but here it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you add the framework to `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` in your project?

Comment: If you're talking about linked frameworks and libraries into build phases or general, yes.

Comment: Remove the `iAd.framework`, clean the project, and add the `iAd.framework` again. Try starting a new project and just implementing iAd too see if the same issue occurs.

Comment: I already did it.. I've resolved that problem only by creating a new project and by pasting into it the code from the previous project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iAd Banner is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267770/iad-banner-is-not-working)